# Amazon RDS: Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am getting this exception from my web application which is using Amazon RDS database.
It's giving error..
Fatal error encountered during command execution. It's random but frequent.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: What were you doing to generate the error? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.